# How to secure RabbitMQ connection string for EasyNetQ and c#?

Tags: c#, rabbitmq, connection-string, application-settings

I need to read the connection string from the config file but I dont like the idea of saving the password in clear

```
RabbitHutch.CreateBus("host=MYHOST;username=MYUSER;password=MYPWD", sr => sr.Register<IEasyNetQLogger>(_ => new RabbitMQLogger()))
```

What would it be a best practice? The question is not just about how to secure strings/settings but also how to secure RabbitMQ connection details.

Comment: Versions I'm using are: RabbitMQ client 3.5.6, EasyNetQ 0.50.12, C# 4.5

Answer (score -3, accepted):

I probably found the answer

```
public static IBus CreateMessageBus()
{
    var connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["easynetq"];
    if (connectionString == null || connectionString.ConnectionString == string.Empty)
    {
        throw new VaultServiceException("easynetq connection string is missing or empty");
    }

    return RabbitHutch.CreateBus(connectionString.ConnectionString);
}
```